# Develop OpenIdConnect Server

Tags: .net, openid-connect, identityserver3

I am trying to develop a client/server apps that work with openid connect. For the client part I used this article https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/06/29/oidc-user-auth-aspnet-core and I succeded to login with an external server. 
 For the server part I have to use an existing IdentityServer3 (a webapi developed with .net 4.6) 
So I added a Client with redirectUrl = http://localhost:65270/signin-oidc and FlowValue=0 (AuthorizationCode), and changed in my client ClientId, ClientSecret and Authority and was able to open the authentification form of the server app from the client. After authentification I got logged-in in the server app and redirected to http://localhost:65270/signin-oidc and I got 500 error. How can I change the server app so it will log the user to the client app? Do I need to add specific cookies or additional data before redirection so that the redirection will be handled by the appropriate client middleware. i found on the internet many example on how to connect a client to an additional server  but I didn't found something on what data need to be send from the identityprovider to the client[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all - are you sure it is http and not https in your url. I'll suggest first try changing this.

Then - your Okta application should redirect back to your IDS not to your client. Then it is Identity Server's job to redirect back to the client. From what you said I understand that http://localhost:65270 is your client url and you are trying to redirect from Okta straight to it (correct me if I'm wrong).